# Optimizing a join between two records of the same table

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to search through a database and find two records in the same table that are inserted in a particular matter. This will tell me where some optimizations must be done in the system.

I have tried a lot of queries, and one finally gave me the right results:

```
SELECT woh.*
FROM workorderhistory woh 
WHERE woh.operation = 'REQ_CONVER' AND woh.operationtime > (
    SELECT MAX(woh2.operationtime) FROM workorderhistory woh2 WHERE woh2.operation = 'CLOSE' 
) AND woh.workorderid = woh2.workorderid
ORDER BY woh.workorderid DESC
LIMIT 100
```

However this one took 1,5 HOURS, on 16000 RECORDS...
So that's a definitely no for me...

The biggest problem in the query is that I only need to match my criteria with the latest `closed` record.

The data will explain more:
[image: Two data tables]

In example one, the query is easy:

```
SELECT woh.*
FROM workorderhistory woh 
INNER JOIN workorderhistory woh2
ON woh.workorderid = woh2.workorderid
WHERE woh.operation = 'REQ_CONVER' AND woh2.operation = 'CLOSE' AND woh.operationtime > woh2.operationtime
```

However, I need to first retrieve the lastly closed record. This is the comparing record that I need.

I tried doing this using INNER JOIN with subquery:

```
SELECT woh.*, woh2.operationtime AS woh2operationtime, woh2.operationtime AS woh2operationtime
FROM workorderhistory woh 
INNER JOIN (SELECT workorderid, operationtime FROM workorderhistory WHERE operation = 'CLOSE' ORDER BY historyid DESC LIMIT 1) woh2
ON woh.workorderid = woh2.workorderid AND woh2.operationtime < woh.operationtime
WHERE woh.operation = 'REQ_CONVER'
ORDER BY woh.workorderid ASC
LIMIT 100
```

But it did not return the right results, it still used the first `CLOSE` record.

Any idea how to optimize this (imo super-simple) query for PostgresSQL?

Comment: You only want the final CLOSE record for each workorderid? Or also the records that come after it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope i understood your question right.

```
SELECT woh.*
FROM workorderhistory woh
join (select max(operationtime) as operationtime , workorderid 
      from workorderhistory 
      where operation = 'CLOSE' group by workorderid 
     ) woh2 
on woh.workorderid = woh2.workorderid
where woh.operationtime > woh2.operationtime
   and operation = 'REQ_CONVER'
```

An Index on column workorderid will improve the performance.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but it is not what I am looking for. This is of course because  I do not have the best explanation of the data.
What I needed is to find all `REQ_CONVER` operations that exist after a `CLOSE` operation to be shown. If I change your query to the right parameters, it is very fast though, so thank you for that !

Comment: update query - now you get all "REQ_CONVER" after last 'CLOSE'

Comment: Thank you very much, I was having a few false positives, but this was because your GROUP BY clause in the subquery is incorrect. Very well done though, by fixing the subquery, this is the fastest query :)

Subquery must be `SELECT  max(operationtime) AS operationtime, workorderid  
FROM workorderhistory  
WHERE operation = 'CLOSE' 
GROUP BY workorderid`. Without the operationtime that is

Comment: 330 ms, so you won this optimization challenge :D

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
Drop table if exists TMP_ workorderhistory;
Create temp table TMP_ workorderhistory as
SELECT 
    Workorderid
  , operationtime 
From (
       SELECT 
          Workorderid
        , operationtime 
        , row_number() over(partition by Workorderid order by historyid desc) AS RNO
       FROM workorderhistory 
       WHERE operation = 'CLOSE' 
     ) A
Where A.RNO = 1;

SELECT woh.*
FROM workorderhistory woh 
INNER JOIN TMP_ workorderhistory woh2
ON woh.workorderid = woh2.workorderid
WHERE woh.operation = 'REQ_CONVER' AND woh.operationtime > woh2.operationtime;
```

Comment: A temp table, I should've come up with that.
Thank you very much, 770ms now :D